# how to transfer markeroptions to different activity

Tags: android

i have 2 markeroptions from mainactivity and want to transfer it to bookingactivity.
i have tried this code :

```
private MarkerOptions from;
private MarkerOptions to;

from = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
to = getIntent().getStringExtra("to");
```

but of course it give me error because the type is String, not MarkerOptions.
how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `MarkerOptions` implements `Parcelable` interface.

So you can try like this :

- When you build `intent`
  `intent.putExtra("from", from)`; // It works because `putExtra(String, Parcelable)` is called.
- When you retrieve `MarkerOptions`
  `MarkOptions from = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("from");`